# Python: Passing and executing class method on object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have simple class and object

```
class Cat():
    def pet(self):
        print('mrrrrrr')

puss = Cat()
```

Is there a builtin method for mechanism like this:

```
cat_sound = ???(puss, Cat.pet)
```

So I can **separately pass and use object and its class function** in nice way?

And I know that I can:

```
cat_sound = getattr(puss, 'pet')
cat_sound()
```

And:

```
 catsound = getattr(puss, Cat.pet.__name__)
 catsound()
```

Even this way what solves my problem but looks ugly:

```
 catsound = getattr(puss, getattr(Cat.pet, '__name__'))
 catsound()
```

**EDIT:**
The another way is to call:

```
 Cat.pet(puss)
```

But my question is still open :)

Comment: What underlying problem are you trying to solve? If you know the method through the class, you can call it directly on the instance, so your question doesn't make yet make sense to me.

Comment: I wish to simply check how to pass separately object and its class method through some function and just wondering if presented in my question method exist. Anyway calling `Cat.Miau(puss)` do the job - but still, my question remain unanswered :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simpler solution than:

```
Cat.pet(puss)
```

Why does this work? Simple because `self` and object instance `puss` is the same object in the memory so when you will try to call `Cat.pet()` without any attribute, you will get `TypeError: pet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` so you know what needs to be passed.
Now you can create a simple function like that:

```
def method_executor(method_ref, obj_instance, *args, **kwargs):
    return method_ref(obj_instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

`args` and `kwargs` are added to maintain possibility passing values to other attributes and use it like that:

```
method_executor(Cat.pet, puss)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `miau` instead of `pet` in your class definition.
Then you can simply do

```py
cat_sound = puss.miau
cat_sound()
```

Comment: Indeed - I made mistake :) Anyway - general concept is to pass separately instance and class function for future usage, and its execution :D